# Looking for children’s illustrated book about a boy, injured goose, and letting goose return to flock

Tags: identification-request

The Wild Goose Flies is in my memory as the title but that doesn’t bring up anything relevant when I search. The book was published in the 1960’s. The boy made a pen for the goose and nursed it back to health. He noticed her missing the other geese when they flew over, so he realized he couldn’t keep her any longer. Beautifully illustrated. A quietly moving book.

Comment: Welcome to Literature Stack Exchange, take our [tour]! Please look through the [identification-request wiki](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/info) and, if any of the prompts there jog your memory, please [edit] this question. For example, what style were the illustrations (Color, pen-and-ink, sketches; catoony or realistic; etc.)? Where was the book from? How large was it (length, cover area)? Was it hardcover or softcover or a board book? Any detail may help.

Comment: [*The Snow Goose*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1209095.The_Snow_Goose) by Paul Gallico? I feel like you would have mentioned the hunchback.